# Updating a frame dynamically doesnt work

Tags: ios, uiview, frame

I am trying to resize a frame of a view upon appearance of a keyboard

changing this view's frame size height does not seem to change the frame size

```
CGRect frame = self.bounds;
    frame.origin = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    frame = UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(frame, UIEdgeInsetsMake(CGRectGetHeight(self.tableHeaderView.frame), 0, 0, 0));
    frame.size.height -= self.contentInset.top;
    frame.size.height -= 300;
    view.frame = frame;
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
    view.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth);
```

the problem is, when i apply the new frame to the view 
view.frame = frame;

the view's frame doesnt actually change

Comment: `NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(frame));` before and after might help to get insight?

Comment: the frame is different, it is the size that i want, but when i apply it to the view , and look at what is displayed on the screen, it does not take the frame i want

Comment: @Lena Bru, did you create your view from nib or storyboard? It's suggested modify constraints rather than modifying frames

Comment: @LenaBru I agree with Azat, you probably have constraints set for that view loaded from Storyboard. So the best you could do is to make outlets for constraints and modify them when keyboard shows up.

Comment: how do i make an outlet for a constraint ?

Comment: @LenaBru, just as usual, ctrl and drag from it to your source code file or create a property manually `@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *constraintName`

Comment: Oh my stars!!!! I really wish i had known about this before. Thank you! I changed the constant of the constraint, and it changed as i wanted